# How to run Visual Studio 2019 experimental by default from Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2019, vsix, visual-studio-2022

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 to develop an extension to Visual Studio 2019.

During the development, I want to deploy the extension to the Visual Studio 2019 experimental instance.
In addition, I want to do it by default. (Which means that every developer don't need to configure it by itself)

To achieve it, I added the following `PropertyGroup` to the `.csproj.user` file of the extension project:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <StartProgram>C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe</StartProgram>
    <DeployTargetInstanceId>**The Instance Id**</DeployTargetInstanceId>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

There are some issues with this approach:

1. `.csproj.user` is a personal setting file that is ignored by git (And I want to keep it that way) which means that I need to configure it on any clone of the repo. (I tried to move the `PropertyGroup` to the `.csporj` which didn't work)
2. If I work with a different version of Visual Studio, the `DeployTargetInstanceId` will be different.